# Can't access API with Lambda and API Gateway

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have an aws lambda function that returns the following response:

```
var responseBody = { cost: price };
var response = {
   statusCode: 200,
   headers: {
          "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
     },
    body: JSON.stringify(responseBody),
    isBase64Encoded: false
};

callback(null, response);
```

But I get the following error in my frontend Angular application.

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   'https://xxxxxxxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/price' from
>   origin 'http://127.0.0.1:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy:
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It
>   does not have HTTP ok status.

Comment: You are being blocked at the API level. Not your lambda. You may want to add that configuration.

Answer (score 14):

If you are using API Gateway HTTP APIs (not sure if this is relevant for the REST APIs):

Lets say I have an endpoint at `/POST products`. I had to add **another endpoint** at `/OPTIONS products` and integrate it with a simple Lambda function that just returns the HTTP 200 OK (or HTTP 204 No Content), and the `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"` header (or even better, specify the URL of your origin/client).

This is because browsers issue a preflight `/OPTIONS` request to the same endpoint, before issuing the actual request (see [more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request)), for all HTTP requests except `GET` and `POST` with certain MIME types ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#functional_overview)).

Comment: Could not find this information anywhere else. Thanks

Comment: Just to add to this, I also didn't see it anywhere else, I really assumed API Gateway would know what to do with a req method OPTIONS. if the lamba is small/cheap, you can check for options at the beginning of execution. Be aware the OPTIONS object has a different signature than the API Gateway object, instead of event.httpMethod, I had to use event.requestContext.http.method

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable CORS on your resource using API gateway, check this link to more information https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html

Comment: don't forget to deploy the api after updating this setting!

Comment: Should you really configure CORS on the API GW level as well as on the Lambda?